# how to have multiple addEventListener in one function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and an input. The function works on the input, but I don't know how I can make it so that the function checks for a keydown and a mouse-up event.

```js
function myFunction(){
        console.log('test');
        // // Get the input field
        var el = document.getElementById("myInput");
        el.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            console.log(input)
            localStorage.setItem("storageName",input);
            console.log('Sending data');
            document.location = 'search.php';
        }
        })
```

```html
<div class="searchbarhome">
   <button id="glas" onclick="myFunction()"for="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
   <input class="searchbox" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Zoek workshops.." title="Type in a name">
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but how do you expect the request to search.php to send the data? Storing it in localStorage is not going to help get it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current logic you have is wrong: in HTML you have attached `myFunction` as `keyup` handler to the `input` element, but then inside `myFunction`, you attach yet again an event handler to the `input` element. This practically means that every time the user releases a key in the input control, a new event handler is accumulated to that `input` element. This is going to accumulate...

Instead, remove the `onclick` and `keypress` attributes from your HTML and use `addEventListener` only.

Some other issues:

- Storing something in `localStorage` is not going to get the string to the PHP server.
- The `for` attribute has no meaning for a `button` element.

Then to your core question: just isolate the common part from what both events should do. As the check for the Enter-key is only for the event on the `input` element -- and not for the button event -- that part should not be in the common function.

Here is how it could look:

```js
const inputElem = document.getElementById("myInput");
const buttonElem = document.getElementById("glas");

inputElem.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") process();
});

buttonElem.addEventListener("click", process);

function process() { // Function with the common logic
    // Common code:
    console.log('test', inputElem.value);
    // Other logic...
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbarhome">
    <button id="glas">Search</button>
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Zoek workshops.." title="Type in a name">
</div>
```